# Changing fragments - improve this if it is possible

Tags: java, android

I'm working on fragment adding/changing, because I'm a beginner I will show you, how I'm doing it.

If someone can do better, with less code, please show me.

So I have ActivityUtils:

```
public abstract class ActivityUtils extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static void addFragment(FragmentManager manager, Fragment fragment, int frameId){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(frameId, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public static void changeFragment(FragmentManager manager, Fragment fragment, int frameId){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(frameId, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

and in MainActivity I have 2 methods:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment){
    ActivityUtils.addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragment, R.id.fragmentContainer);
}

public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment){
    ActivityUtils.changeFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragment, R.id.fragmentContainer);
}
```

Now we can just call method like this:

example:

```
changeFragment(DatabaseFragment.getInstance());
```

but we need also method in every framgents like this:

for our example

```
 public static Fragment getInstance(){
        return new DatabaseFragment();
    }
```

Something is wrong ? Or professional programmers doing this better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks quit well so far. The only thing you could improve is to avoid duplicate code. Look at this:

```
public abstract class ActivityUtils extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static void addFragment(FragmentManager manager, Fragment fragment, int frameId){
        performTask(manager, fragment, frameId, 1);
    }

    public static void changeFragment(FragmentManager manager, Fragment fragment, int frameId){
        performTask(manager, fragment, frameId, 2);
    }

    private static void performTask(FragmentManager manager, Fragment fragment, int frameId, int taskType) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        switch(taskType){
            case 1:
                transaction.add(frameId, fragment);
                break;
            case 2:
                transaction.replace(frameId, fragment);
                break;
        }

        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

You may have some more lines of code at the moment, but if you decide to add further methods that all have the same pattern except this one line that performs the action, then the approach above is the better one.

Comment: If this comment helped you it would be nice of you could mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below method in your MainActivity to replace the fragment easily.

```
 public void replaceHomeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

If you want to add the replaced fragments in the back stack, simply add this line after the fragmentManager.beginTransaction.

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

We use different approaches to replace fragments and maintaining the back stacks while we click the back button or directly navigating the user to the Main Homefragment. So, if you need anything more you can reach me out here.